# using Microsoft Arc Mouse surface edition on MacBook Air 2015

Tags: bluetooth

I have an ARC mouse (surface edition) which i'd like to pair with my macbook air. I'm running el capitan (os X 10.11.1).

from system preferences/mouse I can't even see the mouse. Is there anything else to try?

as far as I understand, my macbook air is bluetooth 4.0 LE compatible. Not sure whether it's bluetooth smart ready though, which the mouse seems to be.

Comment: Can you find it in system preferences/bluetooth?
Make sure the discover button on the mouse is pressed.
Bluetooth smart is just some protocol making the process more energy efficient, it should connect anyway
edit: damn just too late

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution.

1. Open system settings/bluetooth.
2. switch bluetooth off and back on again, this way it will start scanning for new bluetooth devices
3. click and hold (for 5 seconds) the button on the mouse to start the pairing process. The led lights on the mouse will flash red and green
4. After a few seconds the mouse appears on screen, and next to it a big "PAIR" button.
5. Click it! :)

Answer (score 0):

NO, this mouse does not work anymore with 10.10 or later.

Comment: Can also confirm these steps no longer work. There's some more thorough steps here: https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/fix-bluetooth-mac-3682642/  but they also don't work for me. I'm now on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 but still no dice.